How restrictive is the single-crossing property for a mean-preserving spread?
I am trying to prove some results based on a mean-preserving spread of a distribution, and they basically depend on the distributions satisfying a single-crossing property, like the figure here:
Single-crossing CDFs
I wanted to understand more which conditions the distributions must satisfy for the single-crossing property to hold. For example, assuming that $F$ is continuous and $G$ is generated by adding mean-zero continuous noise $z$ to $F$ (something like: $G =^d F + z$), how restrictive is the assumption that $F,G$ are single-crossing? I played around with some usual continuous distributions and it seems to generally hold (e.g., $F$ uniform and $G$ normal, $F$ and $G$ normal).
Many thanks in advance! This is my first post on StackExchange, hope it's not too confusing.

Are you cooking something about game theory?
